# not able to attach mdf file sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I installed the sql server 2008 enterprise version that i got from mcts 433 prep kit. after installing i tried to attach the adventureworks mdf file and got the error below

"the server principal "mythinkpad\vivek" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context..."

Pls help

Comment: under what account is your sql server service running? Also, try installing the latest service pack.

Comment: it's running under local system account and my os is windows 7. lemme try installing the service pack..

Comment: Did you add your windows login to the server admins group in SQL server?

Comment: can you pls tell me how to do this?

Comment: tried it. it says no permssion

Comment: If you don't have permission to attach the database, and you don't have permission to give yourself the permissions, then you will need to speak to someone who does have permission to assign permissions to give you said permission.

Comment: Just to state it explicitly - Windows 7 requires SQL Server 2008 SP1

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the SQL Server Instance did you make yourself an admin?

If not, did you install the SQL Server in mixed mode or Windows only auth mode?

If you installed in mixed mode login with the sa account with the password that you set during install.  Then you can change the permissions.

If you installed in Windows only mode, and didn't make yourself an admin within the database instance then you'll need to uninstall and reinstall SQL Server making yourself an admin during install.

Answer (score 0):

Try running SQL Server Management Studio with the "run as administrator" option of disable UAC on your OS.  Did you make sure and add MYTHINKPAD\VIVEK to the sysadmin group during the SQL 2008 installation options?